Why does my nextJS app not create a build folder when I run npm run build in react?
I have a next.js project that I am trying to use npm run build on so I can compile it to host on hostinger. Every time I run npm run build it tells me that it complies successfully but I cannot find the folder anywhere. Any suggestions?
I tried changing the script { build: } within the package.json to "react-scripts build && xcopy /f /y build wwwroot", which did not work.
this is my scripts part of my package.json file. { "name": "nextjs-creative-portfolio-starter-code-files", "version": "0.1.0", "private": true, "scripts": { "dev": "next dev", "build": "next build", "start": "next start", "lint": "next lint" },
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */ const nextConfig = {}; export default nextConfig; This is my next.config.mjs file

in your next.config.mjs add this
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  distDir: 'build',
};

export default nextConfig;

Now if you run next build Next.js will use build instead of the default .next folder.
source
